How to extract the values from a dictionary
X = {
    "privileges": [
        {"ns": "", "set": "", "code": 0},
        {"ns": "", "set": "", "code": 1},
        {"ns": "", "set": "", "code": 3},
        {"ns": "", "set": "", "code": 12},
        {"ns": "", "set": "", "code": 14},
    ],
    "whitelist": [],
    "read_quota": 0,
    "write_quota": 0,
}

i would like to get the values of 'code' only. I want the output to list only:
0
1
3
12
14

tried with json.loads but could not extract. Any help ?

Protip: don't use capital letters in variables, and call your variable after "what it represents". That said: get the privileges list, then iterate/use list comprehension? There's nothing particularly special about this dict other than the values you want being "in dicts inside a list inside a dict".

Please post what you actually tried, as opposed to a terse description of it.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good advice about meaningful variable names, but fwiw, using a capital X as a variable is ubiquitous in Python machine learning code.

What's the problem, exactly? What does this have to do with json.loads? What did you try?

@Mark if "what it represents" by convention uses a capital, sure, but this is clearly not a math or "low level" CS situation =)

Rather simple using a list comprehension:
output = [privilege["code"] for privilege in X["privileges"]]

